# C# - IEnumerable<> StackOverFlowException (AVLTree)

Tags: c#, ienumerable, avl-tree

I am having an issue with using `IEnumerable<>`

I am reading in a CSV File, I have my get/set methods sorted and I have tested my code before implementing `IEnumerable<>` and the Autos/Locals are displayed correctly.

I'm trying to display the CSV file's content within a DataGridView

```
foreach (Country country in avlTree)
                    {

                      displayCountriesDataGridView.Rows.Add(country.CountryName, country.GDPGrowth, country.Inflation, country.TradeBalance, country.HDIRank, country.TradingPartners);

                    }
```

And using an AVLTree and the `InsertItem` method I have wrote to append this data to the AVLTree

```
  avlTree.InsertItem(tempCountry);
```

This problem arises when I use:

```
class AVLTree<T> : BSTree<T>, IEnumerable<Country> where T : IComparable
```

I have implemented the interfaces :

```
 public IEnumerator<Country> GetEnumerator()
        {

            return this.GetEnumerator();

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {

            return GetEnumerator();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


    }
```

However, no luck what-so-ever.

In the Locals, I get this output-

```
$exception {"Exception of type "System.StackOverflowException' was thrown"}
```

I get a red-cross and the name `this` with the value `Unable to read memory`

And `Type Variables T` has the value `System.__Canon`

I implemented `IEnumerable<>` in my Country class and no issues.

I just can't seem to understand what is causing this issue.

Could someone please offer some guidance or shed light on this matter.

Thank you.

EDIT - Implementation of my AVLTree

```
   class AVLTree<T> : BSTree<T>, IEnumerable<Country> where T : IComparable
    {

        Node<T> newRoot;



        public new void InsertItem(T item)
        {
            insertItem(item, ref root);
        }



        private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
            {
                tree = new Node<T>(item);
            }

            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
            }
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
            {
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);
            }

            tree.BalanceFactor = Height(ref tree.Left) - Height(ref tree.Right);

            if (tree.BalanceFactor <= -2)
            {
                rotateLeft(ref tree);
            }
            if (tree.BalanceFactor >= 2)
            {
                rotateRight(ref tree);
            }
        }




        private void rotateRight(ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Left.BalanceFactor < 0)
            {
                rotateLeft(ref tree.Left);
            }
            newRoot = tree.Left;
            tree.Left = newRoot.Right;
            newRoot.Right = tree;
            tree = newRoot;

        }


        private void rotateLeft(ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Right.BalanceFactor > 0)
            {
                rotateRight(ref tree.Right);
            }

            newRoot = tree.Right;
            tree.Right = newRoot.Left;
            newRoot.Left = tree;
            tree = newRoot;

        }

        public IEnumerator<Country> GetEnumerator()
        {
            // Some iterator/loop which uses "yield return" for each item

        }


        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint, step through the code? Your methods are calling themselves. Why do you implement `IEnumerable<T>`? What is `BSTree<T>`?

Comment: @CodeCaster This is another class, I have a BSTree, BinaryTree and AVLTree as well as a Node class which has the Left, Right, T Data and BalanceFactor getters/setters.

Comment: Your GetEnumerator keeps calling itself. It will of course cause stack overflow. A debugger would show immediately this problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How would I eliminate this loop?

Comment: `GetEnumerator` does nothing but call itself which results in the exception. If you've implemented it in your base class you should just be able to remove this version.

Comment: @Lee I can't as I'm using `foreach (Country country in avlTree)` in my FormClass and I must implemented an IEnumerable inteface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually implement an enumerator. Right now your implementation loops infinitely by calling itself -- no enumerator is returned.

```
public IEnumerator<Country> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Some iterator/loop which uses "yield return" for each item
    foreach (var item in items)
        yield return item;
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. My mistake is becoming more and more apparent. Just one question Isn't it meant to be `foreach` and instead of `var item` couldn't it be `Country item`? I've never used this. Also I'm struggling with the `in (?)`. All I have is a `Node<T>`, `rotateLeft`, `rotateRight` and `insertItem`. In my AVLTree class.

Comment: Yes. `Country item` and `var item` mean the same thing. You can write any sort of for/foreach/while loop you like. The important part is to `yield return` each item. https://www.dotnetperls.com/yield

Comment: I'm just struggling to understand the `in (...)`. What should I put? `foreach (Country item in ... )` .

Comment: Can you post some code with how you typically walk your tree? Then I can adapt the answer based on your usage.

Comment: So, the logic for how you would like to walk the tree isn't clear. It isn't a simple linear flow. Are you hoping to list every item on all branches? Are you hoping to walk one branch? Are you walking from trunk to leaf or from leaf to trunk? 

It is likely that you will need to design the iteration flow, and then it will be easy for you to write the code.

Comment: Basically, I wish to read in a CSV file and use either a ListView or a DataGridView and display each column of the CSV file seperately i.e. CountryName, Inflation, GDP etc. I wish to load the CSV file's contents into the datastructure; AVLTree. And from there on remove, update, display, create, sort.

Comment: A simpler solution might be to load the CSV into a List<Country>, and then separately use an instance of AVLTree. Then you can populate your DataGridView from the List. I'm not sure that a DataGridView really is the right control for displaying Trees. Does that seem possible?

Comment: How would I do that? I understand create a new instance of a List<Country> but to append iit to the AVLTree?

Comment: You could have the code who calls `tree.InsertItem()` also call `list.Add()`, and similar for remove/change/etc.

Comment: I have this, thus far `private AVLTree<Country> avlTree = new AVLTree<Country>();`, I create a temporary instance of a country `private LinkedList<String> tempCountry;` and after iterating through I use `avlTree.InsertItem(tempCountry);`

Comment: This sounds like a different scenario than the original question. If you are having a problem when implementing that, create a new StackOverflow question with the appropriate code, and I can help you out. I believe that the current issue (StackOverflow on GetEnumerator) has been answered.

Comment: I appreciate your help, still don't know what to do though when I type `in ...` . But none-the-less, thanks for your help.

Comment: You an use `foreach` syntax in anything with an Enumerator. ```IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in strings)
    Console.WriteLine(str);```

Comment: Thanks, bud! Worked a charm, have another error but isn't in correlation to this. I'll accept your answer.